# Some Course/book about FPGA?

Tags: fpga

I'm starting my journey with FPGAs and I bought a low cost with this specifications :

> FPGA: EP2C8Q208C8N
>   SDRAM: 256 M bit/ 36 M Byte
>   CFI_FLASH: 64 M bit/ou 8 M Byte
>   SRAM: 256 K x 16/ 4 M bit
>   EPCS: EPCS16/ M25P32 (Configure FPGA)
>   CLK_INPUT: 50 MHz

Does anyone suggest me any course/book about fpgas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bought Cyclone II FPGA from Altera. In that case you should start with courses available on [Altera Training website](https://www.altera.com/support/training/overview.html). This courses cover a lot interesting subjects (for beginners as well as more experienced engineers), for example:

- starting course called [Become an FPGA Designer in 4 Hours](http://www.altera.com/education/training/courses/ODSWBECOME),
- basics of HDL - [Verilog](http://www.altera.com/education/training/courses/OHDL1120) or [VHDL](http://www.altera.com/education/training/courses/OHDL1110), depending which one you'd choose,
- basics of [Altera Quartus II](http://www.altera.com/education/training/courses/ODSW1100) - software tool produced by Altera for analysis and synthesis of HDL designs,
- usage of Nios II processor.